# .htaccess rewriterule to php page not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I've configured as follows

```
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?mydomain.com/.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .(gif|jpg|swf|flv|png)$ /feed/ [R=302,L]
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8


    <ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
    </ifModule>

    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=37739520, public"
    </FilesMatch>

    RewriteCond /%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule (.*).htm$ /$1.php [R=301,L]

    ErrorDocument 400 /errore/errore.php?error=400
    ErrorDocument 401 /errore/errore.php?error=401
    ErrorDocument 403 /errore/errore.php?error=403
    ErrorDocument 404 /errore/errore.php?error=404
    ErrorDocument 500 /errore/errore.php?error=500


    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteRule ^folder/([a-zA-Z]{2})$  /folder/$1/ [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^folder/([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*)$  /folder/$2?lang=$1 [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^folder/miky/(.*)$ /folder/miky.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^folder/pippo/(.*)$ /folder/pippo.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The first two lines of redirect rules are for language extension.

Typing *www.mydomain.com/en/folder/miky/123456*, I obtain *www.mydomain.com/folder/miky/123456* OK

Thus, typing: *www.mydomain.com/en/folder/pippo/123456*
I should be redirected to: *www.mydomain.com/folder/pippo.php?id=123456*
However, it doesn't work.

On the other hand, typing *www.mydomain.com/folder/pippo/123456* I'm correctly redirected to *www.mydomain.com/folder/pippo.php?id=123456*

Ok, I solved it.
The problem was an erroneous reuse of the word for two different paths.

Comment: Ought `RewriteEngine On` be at the top?

Comment: `^folder/pippo/(.*)/?$` ought to cover both.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles "ReqriteEngine On" need to stay before RewriteRules declaration, as it is.

Comment: Does this cond/rule capture it first? `RewriteCond /%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f`

Comment: No, it is not. I see that it is something related to language extension

Answer (score 0):

just try next:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /  
    RewriteRule ^pippo/(.*) /folder/pippo.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^pippo /folder/pippo.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```